# what's wrong with this vhdl code?

Tags: vhdl

this structural counter must count in this way:
0...9 0...9 0..3  and again... 
i think my problems are at the istances at the end, in gtk wave I have problems only with the counter2! I don't know why, please help...

[circuit.. http://www.cromo-pharma.it/circuito.jpg](http://www.cromo-pharma.it/circuito.jpg)

```
            ---------component instantiations-----------

                signal sR2, sE2, sR1 : std_logic;
                signal s2, s3, s8 : std_logic;
                signal s0sec, s1sec, s2sec : std_logic;
                signal c1out, c2out : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
                signal dec1out, dec2out : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);

                begin

                i2: counter1 port map (clk => clk, reset => sR1, count1 => c1out);
                i3: counter2 port map (clk => clk, reset => sR2, en2 => sE2, count2 => c2out);
                i5: deco port map (binary_in => c1out, decoder_out => dec1out);
                i6: deco port map (binary_in => c2out, decoder_out => dec2out);

                sR1 <= ((s8 and (s0sec or s1sec)) or (s2sec and s2)) or reset;
                sR2 <= (s2 and s2sec);
                sE2 <= s8;

                s2 <= dec1out(2); --_a _b c _d 0010
                s3 <= dec1out(3); --_a _b c d 0011
                s8 <= dec1out(8); -- a _b _c _d 1000
                s0sec <= dec2out(0); -- _a _b _c _d 0000
                s1sec <= dec2out(1); -- _a _b _c d 0001
                s2sec <= dec2out(2); -- _a _b c _d 0010

                i4: data_out <= c1out;
            ---------------end----------------

            --decoder--
              architecture dec of deco is 
              begin
                    decoder_out <= "1000000000000000" when binary_in="1111" else
                                   "0100000000000000" when binary_in="1110" else
                                   "0010000000000000" when binary_in="1101" else
                                   "0001000000000000" when binary_in="1100" else
                                   "0000100000000000" when binary_in="1011" else
                                   "0000010000000000" when binary_in="1010" else
                                   "0000001000000000" when binary_in="1001" else
                                   "0000000100000000" when binary_in="1000" else
                                   "0000000010000000" when binary_in="0111" else
                                   "0000000001000000" when binary_in="0110" else
                                   "0000000000100000" when binary_in="0101" else
                                   "0000000000010000" when binary_in="0100" else
                                   "0000000000001000" when binary_in="0011" else
                                   "0000000000000100" when binary_in="0010" else
                                   "0000000000000010" when binary_in="0001" else
                                   "0000000000000001" when binary_in="0000" else
                                   "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
            end architecture dec;

                   --counter with enable--

            entity counter2 is
                port (  clk : in std_logic;
                        reset : in std_logic;
                        count2 : out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
                        en2 : in std_logic
                        );
            end entity counter2;

            architecture RTL of counter2 is

            begin
                 process (clk, reset, en2) is -- processo di verifica
                  variable cnt : unsigned(3 downto 0);
                begin
                  if reset = '1' then cnt := (others => '0');
                  elsif rising_edge(clk) and en2='1' then 
                        if en2 = '1' then cnt := cnt + 1;
                        end if;
                  end if;
                  count2 <= std_logic_vector(cnt); 
                end process;

                         --standard counter--

                entity counter1 is
                    port (  clk : in std_logic;
                            reset : in std_logic;
                            count1 : out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0)  
                            );
                end entity counter1;

                architecture RTL of counter1 is

                begin
                     process (clk, reset) is -- processo di verifica
                      variable cnt : unsigned(3 downto 0);
                    begin
                      if reset = '1' then cnt := (others => '0');
                      elsif rising_edge(clk) then cnt := cnt + 1;
                      end if;
                      count1 <= std_logic_vector(cnt); 
                    end process;
```

Comment: Have you double checked the expressions when assigning sR1, sR2, sE2? They are not readily obvious, so you might want to add some comments (or write simpler code).

Comment: What is the problem?  What behaviour are you seeing that is incorrect?  Can you post some pictures of waveforms, or sequences of signal values and point out what should be different?

Comment: @MartinThompson Hi! Thanks for answering. Every connection about counter1 works great (except for R1 signal). Every connections about counter2 return in gtkwave a red value ("U"). I don't understand why. If this didn't help I will put a screen from the waveform! Thanks.

Comment: @Paul Hi! Thanks for answering. I put a graph for a better understanding of my counter. Thanks!

Comment: Do `counter1` and `counter2` work on their own? Are there any Us elsewhere?  Possibly edit your question to post the code for the counters and `deco` whatever that is.  Try and reduce the lines of code though, as we all have to wade through it!

Comment: @MartinThompson Hi! I changed codes. (deco is a decoder). If you consider some lines of code not useful tell me and I'll remove.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually say what the problem you're seeing is. That makes it difficult to help.

First thing is whilst I can assume what the function of the counter blocks are, the deco block is a mystery. What is it?

```
            s2 <= dec1out(2); --_a _b c _d 0010
            s3 <= dec1out(3); --_a _b c d 0011
            s8 <= dec1out(8); -- a _b _c _d 1000
            s0sec <= dec2out(0); -- _a _b _c _d 0000
            s1sec <= dec2out(1); -- _a _b _c d 0001
            s2sec <= dec2out(2); -- _a _b c _d 0010
```

These would suggest that the deco block gives a one-hot encoding of the value, is that correct? In which case your comments are misleading.

```
            sR1 <= ((s8 and (s0sec or s1sec)) or (s2sec and s2)) or reset;
            sR2 <= (s2 and s2sec);
            sE2 <= s8;
```

You aren't resetting counter2 on reset, but ignoring that and rewriting these in English

```
Reset counter1 when counter1 is 8 and counter2 is [0..1] or    -- 00..08, 10..18
                    counter1 is 2 and counter2 is 2            -- 20..22
Reset counter2 when counter1 is 2 and counter2 is 2            -- 22
Enable counter2 when counter1 when is 8                        -- 08, 18
```

Aren't you doing everything a cycle too early? Enabling and resetting on 8 and not 9.

Answer (score 2):

Without going into detail I think you should change your strategy to a finite state machine with a single set/reset timer. Then you can set the time delay in each state and reset it in between. You could drive a signal indicating the end of a certain count high on the transitions between states. The code would be much neater than what you have